# Foreign key constraint fails for table `inventory1`.`asset_details`: ERROR

Tags: php, mysql

This is the error message I get when I run the show DB innobd status command . I am new to php and mysql and any help will be appreciated . Thank you in advance .

When I submit data into my database, the information goes into the asset tables but not the assert_details ?

```
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
120811 22:40:43 Transaction:
TRANSACTION 1A4F, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 73, OS thread handle 0x10ccc4000, query id 339 localhost root update
INSERT INTO asset_details (asset_type,make, model, serial_number, os,os_version,memory, hdd, processor,notes)
            Values( 'Monitor','Apple ','Mac Book Pro 17 inch ','65655453445545','Macintosh','Snow Lion ','5 gb ','1 TB','Intel i 9','This is Paskale New Mac book pro computer.')
Foreign key constraint fails for table `inventory1`.`asset_details`:
,
  CONSTRAINT `asset_tag` FOREIGN KEY (`asset_tag`) REFERENCES `asset` (`asset_tag`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
Trying to add in child table, in index `asset_tag` tuple:
DATA TUPLE: 2 fields;
 0: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;

But in parent table `inventory1`.`asset`, in index `PRIMARY`,
the closest match we can find is record:
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 8; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000007; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000001a4f; asc      O;;
 2: len 7; hex c0000001d40110; asc        ;;
 3: SQL NULL;
 4: len 14; hex 4465636f6d6d697373696f6e6564; asc Decommissioned;;
 5: SQL NULL;
 6: len 7; hex 4d6f6e69746f72; asc Monitor;;
 7: SQL NULL;
```

This is the script to create the tables in my database .

This the script to create the the tables

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `inventory1` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `inventory1` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
USE `inventory1` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inventory1`.`department`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `inventory1`.`department` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory1`.`department` (
  `department_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `department_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `job_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`department_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inventory1`.`employee`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `inventory1`.`employee` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory1`.`employee` (
  `employee_id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `department_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `fname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `lname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `phone_number` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `hire_date` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `job_id` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `manager_id` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`) ,
  INDEX `department_id` (`department_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `department_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`department_id` )
    REFERENCES `inventory1`.`department` (`department_id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inventory1`.`invoice`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `inventory1`.`invoice` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory1`.`invoice` (
  `invoice_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `invoice_number` INT NULL ,
  `invoice_date` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `purchase_price` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `quantity` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `order_date` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `vender` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `warranty_end` DATE NULL ,
  `notes` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`invoice_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inventory1`.`asset`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `inventory1`.`asset` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory1`.`asset` (
  `asset_tag` INT NOT NULL ,
  `invoice_id` INT NULL ,
  `status` VARCHAR(25) NULL ,
  `cap_ex` VARCHAR(20) NULL ,
  `asset_type` VARCHAR(25) NULL ,
  `invoice_number` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`asset_tag`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `invoice_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`invoice_id` )
    REFERENCES `inventory1`.`invoice` (`invoice_id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inventory1`.`location`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `inventory1`.`location` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory1`.`location` (
  `location_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `location_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `rack` INT NULL ,
  `row` INT NULL ,
  `unit` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inventory1`.`physical_asset`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `inventory1`.`physical_asset` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory1`.`physical_asset` (
  `physical_asset_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `location_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `employee_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `physical_asset_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`physical_asset_id`) ,
  INDEX `location_id` (`location_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `employee_id` (`employee_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `location_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`location_id` )
    REFERENCES `inventory1`.`location` (`location_id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `employee_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id` )
    REFERENCES `inventory1`.`employee` (`employee_id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inventory1`.`asset_details`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `inventory1`.`asset_details` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory1`.`asset_details` (
  `asset_id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `asset_tag` INT NOT NULL ,
  `physical_asset_id` INT NULL ,
  `asset_type` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `manufacturer` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `os` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `os_version` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `make` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `model` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `serial_number` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `processor` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `ram` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `memory` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `hdd` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `host_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `notes` VARCHAR(250) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`asset_id`) ,
  INDEX `physical_asset_id` (`physical_asset_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `asset_tag` (`asset_tag` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `physical_asset_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`physical_asset_id` )
    REFERENCES `inventory1`.`physical_asset` (`physical_asset_id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `asset_tag`
    FOREIGN KEY (`asset_tag` )
    REFERENCES `inventory1`.`asset` (`asset_tag` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;



SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;


    LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
    ------------------------
    120811 22:40:43 Transaction:
    TRANSACTION 1A4F, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
    mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
    4 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
    MySQL thread id 73, OS thread handle 0x10ccc4000, query id 339 localhost root update
    INSERT INTO asset_details (asset_type,make, model, serial_number, os,os_version,memory, hdd, processor,notes)
                Values( 'Monitor','Apple ','Mac Book Pro 17 inch ','65655453445545','Macintosh','Snow Lion ','5 gb ','1 TB','Intel i 9','This is Paskale New Mac book pro computer.')
    Foreign key constraint fails for table `inventory1`.`asset_details`:
    ,
      CONSTRAINT `asset_tag` FOREIGN KEY (`asset_tag`) REFERENCES `asset` (`asset_tag`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    Trying to add in child table, in index `asset_tag` tuple:
    DATA TUPLE: 2 fields;
     0: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
     1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;

    But in parent table `inventory1`.`asset`, in index `PRIMARY`,
    the closest match we can find is record:
    PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 8; compact format; info bits 0
     0: len 4; hex 80000007; asc     ;;
     1: len 6; hex 000000001a4f; asc      O;;
     2: len 7; hex c0000001d40110; asc        ;;
     3: SQL NULL;
     4: len 14; hex 4465636f6d6d697373696f6e6564; asc Decommissioned;;
     5: SQL NULL;
     6: len 7; hex 4d6f6e69746f72; asc Monitor;;
     7: SQL NULL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT :sorry I had misread

What happens is your try to put a line in a table that has foreign keys to other table but does not specify the foreign key id.

You have to set the values of the foreign key ( and have those key existing on the other tables) before inserting into the asset_details table.

So your insert

```
 INSERT INTO asset_details (asset_type,make, model, serial_number, os,os_version,memory, hdd, processor,notes)
        Values( 'Monitor','Apple ','Mac Book Pro 17 inch ','65655453445545','Macintosh','Snow Lion ','5 gb ','1 TB','Intel i 9','This is Paskale New Mac book pro computer.')
```

should also include the `physical_asset_id`

Comment: Okay , But what about if I want this value to be auto incremented ?

Comment: its a forgein key it cannot be auto incremented since its linked to another table. The value of asset_details.physical_asset_id has to be present in physical_asset.physical_asset_id.
what you have to do is creating the tuple in table physical_asset and then take that id and put it in asset_details.physical_asset_id